# Correct setup for multiple web sites with nginx, django and celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, flower

Im trying to find some information on the correct way of setting up multiple django sites on a linode (Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.9.3-x86_64-linode33 x86_64)

Here is what I have now:

Webserver: nginx

Every site is contained in a .virtualenv

Django and other packages is installed using pip in each .virtualenv

RabbitMQ is installed using `sudo apt-get rabbitmq`, and a new user and vhost is created for each site.

Each site is started using supervisor script:

```
[group:<SITENAME>]
programs=<SITENAME>-gunicorn, <SITENAME>-celeryd, <SITENAME>-celerycam


[program:<SITENAME>-gunicorn]
directory = /home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITENAME>/<PROJECT>/
command=/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITENAME>/bin/gunicorn <PROJECT>.wsgi:application -c /home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITENAME>/<PROJECT>/server_conf/<SITENAME>-gunicorn.py

user=<USER>
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stderr_events_enabled = true
redirect_stderr = true
logfile_maxbytes=5MB


[program:<SITENAME>-celeryd]
directory=/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITENAME>/<PROJECT>/
command=/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITENAME>/bin/python /home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITENAME>/<PROJECT>/manage.py celery worker -E -n <SITENAME> --broker=amqp://<SITENAME>:<SITENAME>@localhost:5672//<SITENAME> --loglevel=ERROR
environment=HOME='/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITENAME>/<PROJECT>/',DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='<PROJECT>.settings.staging'

user=<USER>
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600

[program:<SITENAME>-celerycam]
directory=/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITENAME>/<PROJECT>/
command=/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITENAME>/bin/python /home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITENAME>/<PROJECT>/manage.py celerycam
environment=HOME='/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITENAME>/<PROJECT>/',DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='<PROJECT>.settings.staging'

user=<USER>
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
```

---

Question 1: Is this the correct way? Or is it a better way to do this?

Question 2: I have tried to install [celery flower](https://github.com/mher/flower), but how does that work with multiple sites? Do I need to install one flower-package for each .virtualenv, or could I use one install for every site? How do I setup nginx to display the flower-page(s) on my server?

Answer (score 2):

### Answer 1

There are - as so often :) - several ways to go. We do set it up in a similar way.

For the supervisor configuration I would suggest to use a little bit less verbose way, below an example for running web/tasks for 'example.com':

*/etc/supervisor/conf.d/example.com.conf*
(we usually have the config files in the repository as well, and just symlink them. So this file could be a symlink to:
*/var/www/example.com/conf/supervisord.conf*  )

```
[group:example.com]
programs=web, worker, cam

[program:web]
command=/srv/example.com/bin/gunicorn project.wsgi -c /var/www/example.com/app/gunicorn.conf.py
directory=/var/www/example.com/app/

user=<USER>
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=True
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stdout_logfile_backups=5
stdout_logfile=/var/log/apps/web.example.com.log


[program:worker]
command=/srv/example.com/bin/celery -A project worker -l info
directory=/var/www/example.com/app/

user=<USER>
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=True
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stdout_logfile_backups=5
stdout_logfile=/var/log/apps/web.example.com.log


[program:flower]
command=/srv/example.com/bin/celery flower -A project --broker=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//example.com/ --url_prefix=flower --port 5001
directory=/var/www/example.com/app/

...
```

So you have less to type and it is easier to read..

```
# restart all 'programs'
supervisorctl restart example.com:* 

# restart web/django
supervisorctl restart example.com:web

etc.
```

### Answer 2

Not totally sure if it is the best way, but what I would do here (and usually do):

- run *flower* separately for every app (see config above)
  with respective vhost (and url_prefix)
- ad nginx reverse-proxy (directory with same name as url_prefix)

*/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.conf*

```
server {

    ...

    location /flower {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;

        ...
```

Access the flower interface at *example.com/flower*